# Bash vi mode configuration to default to command mode

Tags: bash, vi-mode

Is it possible to configure bash vi mode so that initially it is in **command** mode instead on **insert** mode? I find that I have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> far too much. It seems that there is possibility to specify this in zsh, but I have not found a way to do this in bash/readline.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible using the standard [GNU Readline Library](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html).

However, you may be able to use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool) for a simple hack to achieve the same effect. Appending a command to your `.bashrc` that simulates an <kbd>Escape</kbd> keypress would ensure that your term opened in command mode:

```
xdotool key Escape
```

You might want to use a slight delay, with the `--delay` switch, to prevent it from munging your prompt...

**Note** this is likely to introduce more frustration than you expect: terminals are designed to accept input; breaking that (albeit only slightly) may not prove such a  good idea...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **no**. The relevant bash source file is `bashline.c`

Answer (score 1):

I take it back, this doesn't work with the cursor movement.  It works, but with the funny behavior, if you take those out: `PS1="$PS1 ^[`

---

Change your `PS1` prompt:

```
PS1="test $ \[^[[s^[^[[u\]"
```

Where `^[` is a literal escape (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

The escape on its own in the middle changes to command mode, the `^[[s` and `^[[u` escapes store and restore the cursor position; without that, I found there was some funny behavior.

Answer (score -2):

try `set +o vi`

`set -o vi` will take into editing mode again.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html

Comment: That doesn't work: it turns vi mode off...

Comment: yeah I tried. Right. I can think of this -- using vim, change the cmap (reference :help mode-switching in vim) for `Esc` key. Default equivalent mapping for `Esc` is `Ctrl + ]`