# How can I setup a hybrid readline with emacs insert mode and vi command mode?

Tags: shell, readline

I want a hybrid mode where I can use all the default `keymap emacs` key bindings by default, and still have the ability to change to `vi-command` mode.

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I read [@Tom Hale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/143394/tom-hale)'s answers
[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303632/238373) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303479/what-are-readlines-modes-keymaps-and-their-default-bindings).

I think instead of moving `vi-insert` bindings to `emacs`, the better approach is to move `emacs` bindings to `vi-insert`. The reason is because `vi-command` has bindings that switch to `vi-insert` and it's hard to emulate the functionality to make it switch to `emacs` mode.

For example, the `A` command in `vi-command` defaults to `vi-append-eol` (appending at the end of the line and switch to `vi-insert`).

You can't make `A` switch to `emacs` mode because it is bound to a function and not a macro.

For example, this wouldn't work

```
"A": vi-append-eol emacs-editing-mode
```

Nor this, using [@Tom Hale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/143394/tom-hale)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303632/238373)

```
"A": vi-append-eol "\ee"
```

You could do this:

```
"A": "$a\ee"
```

But now that depends on the `"a"`, `vi-append-mode` command, which also needs to be rebound. `"a"` could be move forward then `"i"`. `"i"` could just switch to `emacs`. There's a whole chain of commands to translate into macros which is a pain to do.

So you are better off moving the `emacs` bindings to `vi-insert`.

---

So we want to set `vi-insert` bindings that are unique to `emacs`
And we want to make a decision on which binding to use if they have different bindings for the same key sequence.
If they have the exact same binding, we ignore them.

This can be done with this command

```
comm -3\
  <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs' |
    LC_ALL='C' grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' |
    sort) \
  <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm vi-insert' |
    LC_ALL='C' grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' |
    sort) | cat
```

The reason why the `| cat` is there is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/409856/238373)

The `-3` throws away the "exact same bindings"
So you go through this list and look for bindings on the left column. For each binding on the left column:

If there is a duplicate binding for the same key sequence, such as

```
"\C-d": delete-char
    "\C-d": vi-eof-maybe
```

Choose one of them. If you want the `vi-insert` one (on the right), you can delete both lines, because we will be adding these bindings to `vi-insert` which already has the `vi-insert` binding. If you want the `emacs` one (on the left), delete the `vi-insert` one.

If there is a unique binding on the right column (`vi-insert`), such as

```
    "\e": vi-movement-mode
```

delete it because `vi-insert already has it.

The rest of the bindings will be on the left column (`emacs`). Leave these alone because we will add these to `vi-insert`.

---

Here is my `.inputrc` with the `emacs` bindings I selected added to `vi-insert`.

I decided not to use the `"kj"` to switch to `vi-command` in [@Tom Hale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/143394/tom-hale)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303632/238373) because it can be done with `"\ee"` which takes you from `emacs` to `vi-insert` then another `"\e"` which takes you from `vi-insert` to `vi-command`. There are actually [words other than blackjack containing kj](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-containing-kj) and [words with jk (mostly place names)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-containing-jk)

I kept `"\C-d": delete-char` and threw away `"\C-d": vi-eof-maybe`. Because I could just use `Enter` for `vi-eof-maybe` and I don't want to accidentally quit readline by pressing `"\C-d"`. This means to delete the `"\C-d": vi-eof-maybe` binding because we are overriding the `vi-eof-maybe` binding in `vi-insert` mode with the `delete-char` binding.

I kept `"\C-n": menu-complete` instead of `"\C-n": next-history` because I could just use down arrow for `next-history`. This means to delete both bindings because `vi-insert` already has the `menu-complete` binding.

I kept `"\C-p": menu-complete-backward` instead of `"\C-p": previous-history` because I could press up arrow for `previous-history`. This means to delete both bindings because `vi-insert` already has the `menu-complete-backward` binding.

I kept `"\C-w": vi-unix-word-rubout` instead of `"\C-w": unix-word-rubout`. I don't know what's the difference. I just stuck with the `vi-insert` one.  This means to delete both bindings because `vi-insert` already has the `vi-unix-word-rubout` binding.

I kept `"\e": vi-movement-mode`. This means to delete this binding because `vi-insert` already has the `vi-movement-mode` binding.

```
set editing-mode vi

set keymap emacs
"\ee": vi-editing-mode

set keymap vi-command
"\ee": emacs-editing-mode

# key bindings to get out of vi-editing-mode
set keymap vi-insert
"\ee": emacs-editing-mode

# emacs keybindings in vi-insert mode
"\C-@": set-mark
"\C-]": character-search
"\C-_": undo
"\C-a": beginning-of-line
"\C-b": backward-char
"\C-d": delete-char
"\C-e": end-of-line
"\C-f": forward-char
"\C-g": abort
"\C-k": kill-line
"\C-l": clear-screen
"\C-o": operate-and-get-next
"\C-q": quoted-insert
"\C-x!": possible-command-completions
"\C-x$": possible-variable-completions
"\C-x(": start-kbd-macro
"\C-x)": end-kbd-macro
"\C-x*": glob-expand-word
"\C-x/": possible-filename-completions
"\C-x@": possible-hostname-completions
"\C-x\C-?": backward-kill-line
"\C-x\C-e": edit-and-execute-command
"\C-x\C-g": abort
"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file
"\C-x\C-u": undo
"\C-x\C-v": display-shell-version
"\C-x\C-x": exchange-point-and-mark
"\C-xe": call-last-kbd-macro
"\C-xg": glob-list-expansions
"\C-x~": possible-username-completions
"\e ": set-mark
"\e!": complete-command
"\e#": insert-comment
"\e$": complete-variable
"\e&": tilde-expand
"\e*": insert-completions
"\e-": digit-argument
"\e.": insert-last-argument
"\e.": yank-last-arg
"\e/": complete-filename
"\e0": digit-argument
"\e1": digit-argument
"\e2": digit-argument
"\e3": digit-argument
"\e4": digit-argument
"\e5": digit-argument
"\e6": digit-argument
"\e7": digit-argument
"\e8": digit-argument
"\e9": digit-argument
"\e<": beginning-of-history
"\e=": possible-completions
"\e>": end-of-history
"\e?": possible-completions
"\e@": complete-hostname
"\e\C-?": backward-kill-word
"\e\C-]": character-search-backward
"\e\C-e": shell-expand-line
"\e\C-g": abort
"\e\C-h": backward-kill-word
"\e\C-i": dynamic-complete-history
"\e\C-r": revert-line
"\e\C-y": yank-nth-arg
"\e\\": delete-horizontal-space
"\e\e": complete
"\e^": history-expand-line
"\e_": insert-last-argument
"\e_": yank-last-arg
"\eb": backward-word
"\ec": capitalize-word
"\ed": kill-word
"\ef": forward-word
"\eg": glob-complete-word
"\el": downcase-word
"\en": non-incremental-forward-search-history
"\ep": non-incremental-reverse-search-history
"\er": revert-line
"\et": transpose-words
"\eu": upcase-word
"\ey": yank-pop
"\e{": complete-into-braces
"\e~": complete-username
```

---

**UPDATE**

I think I made it a little better. For a while, I turned back on the `"jk"` mooshing to switch to `vi command` because pressing `"\e"` to switch to `vi-command` had a delay since a lot of `emacs` commands moved over to `vi-insert` uses `"\e"` as a leader.

This shows the `"jk"` mooshing commented out. I currently use `"\ee"` to cycle modes. I didn't unbind the `"\e"` to switch from `vi-insert` to `vi-command` because I don't see a need. So it has the effect where if you press `"\e"` in `vi-insert` and wait, you will go to `vi-command`.

To get from `vi-command` to `vi-insert`, you'll just press one of the commands such as `"A"` or `"i"` so allowing cycling between 3 modes won't hurt because you can also just cycle between the 2 `vi` modes.

```
set keymap emacs
"\ee": vi-editing-mode

set keymap vi-command
"\ee": emacs-editing-mode

# key bindings to get out of vi-editing-mode
set keymap vi-insert
# Choose one of these editor switching modes
# 
# moosh jk to switch
#"\ee": emacs-editing-mode
#"\ejk": vi-movement-mode
#"\ekj": vi-movement-mode
#
# "\ee" to cycle
# can unmap "\e" to switch to vi-command but don't see a need
#"\e":
"\ee": vi-movement-mode
```

---

**UPDATE**

In `vi-insert`, `"\C-w"` is bound to `vi-unix-word-rubout, which stops at word boundaries or something. I didn't like that functionality.

For example, try this

```
$ cannot-delete'
# press left arrow to go back behind the single quote
# press \C-w in vi-insert to try to delete cannot-delete, it won't work
```

[this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1477328) describes the problem, although I don't have a problem with the example provided.

So you can bind `"\C-w"` to the emacs `unix-word-rubout` to fix this.

To rebind `"\C-w"`, you might need to [unbind defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980575/how-can-i-unbind-and-remap-c-w-in-bash).

```
# In .bashrc
stty werase undef
```

If you would like to unbind all defaults:

```
# In .inputrc
set bind-tty-special-chars off
```

Not sure if it matters, but I am on macOS so there are [other default bindings I remove](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/ctrl-o-behavior-in-terminal-app).

Then in your `.inputrc`:

```
"\C-w": unix-word-rubout
```

Comment: Nice one! Very thorough. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed questions and answers too! They allowed me to improve on the solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

The following `.inputrc` lines allow <kbd>Meta / Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to switch between `emacs` and `vi-insert` modes.

Mooshing both <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> simultaneously will take you to `vi-command` mode.

Note: The only English word with "kj" is "blackjack", no words contain "jk")

```
set show-mode-in-prompt on

set keymap emacs
"\ee": vi-editing-mode
"jk": "\eejk"
"kj": "\eejk"

set keymap vi-insert
"\ee": emacs-editing-mode
"jk": vi-movement-mode
"kj": vi-movement-mode

set keymap vi-command
"\ee": emacs-editing-mode
```

Note: In `bash` v4.3.11(1), if you add a binding under `keymap emacs` to `vi-movement-mode` to try to switch straight to the `vi-command` keymap, the prompt doesn't update if you have `show-mode-in-prompt on`, hence this work-around is needed.

---

Interesting factoids:

There are only 4 bindings unique to `vi-insert` mode, which can be easily added to `emacs` mode:

```
"\C-d": vi-eof-maybe
"\C-n": menu-complete
"\C-p": menu-complete-backward
"\e": vi-movement-mode
```

However note that the following are the default `emacs` bindings:

```
"\C-d": delete-char
"\C-n": next-history
"\C-p": previous-history
```

Which I resolved as follows:

```
set keymap emacs
"\e": "kj" # needs to be below "kj" mapping
"\C-d": delete-char # eof-maybe: ^D does nothing if there is text on the line
"\C-n": menu-complete
"\C-p": menu-complete-backward
"\C-y": previous-history # historY
"\e\C-y": previous-history
```

---

## **Old answer**

This is how I did it before I could go directly from `emacs` to `vi-command`. It involves importing all the default `emacs` commands into the `vi-insert` keymap.

Get the default `emacs-standard` and `vi-insert` mappings:

```
INPUTRC=~/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs-standard' | grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' | sort > emacs-standard
INPUTRC=~/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm vi-insert' | grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' | sort > vi-insert
```

Get only the additions from `emacs-standard`:

```
comm -23  emacs-standard vi-insert > vi-insert-emacs-additions
```

Then, in your `~/.inputrc`, add the content of `vi-insert-emacs-additions` under the lines:

```
(echo set editing-mode vi && echo set keymap vi-insert && cat vi-insert-emacs-additions) >> ~/.inputrc
```

For your convenience, on bash 4.3.11(1)-release, `vi-insert-emacs-additions` contents are:

> ```
> "\C-a": beginning-of-line
> "\C-b": backward-char
> "\C-]": character-search
> "\C-d": delete-char
> "\C-e": end-of-line
> "\C-f": forward-char
> "\C-g": abort
> "\C-k": kill-line
> "\C-l": clear-screen
> "\C-n": next-history
> "\C-o": operate-and-get-next
> "\C-p": previous-history
> "\C-q": quoted-insert
> "\C-@": set-mark
> "\C-_": undo
> "\C-x\C-?": backward-kill-line
> "\C-x\C-e": edit-and-execute-command
> "\C-x\C-g": abort
> "\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file
> "\C-x\C-u": undo
> "\C-x\C-v": display-shell-version
> "\C-x\C-x": exchange-point-and-mark
> "\C-xe": call-last-kbd-macro
> "\C-x)": end-kbd-macro
> "\C-xg": glob-list-expansions
> "\C-x*": glob-expand-word
> "\C-x!": possible-command-completions
> "\C-x/": possible-filename-completions
> "\C-x@": possible-hostname-completions
> "\C-x~": possible-username-completions
> "\C-x$": possible-variable-completions
> "\C-x(": start-kbd-macro
> "\e0": digit-argument
> "\e1": digit-argument
> "\e2": digit-argument
> "\e3": digit-argument
> "\e4": digit-argument
> "\e5": digit-argument
> "\e6": digit-argument
> "\e7": digit-argument
> "\e8": digit-argument
> "\e9": digit-argument
> "\eb": backward-word
> "\e<": beginning-of-history
> "\e\C-?": backward-kill-word
> "\ec": capitalize-word
> "\e\C-]": character-search-backward
> "\e\C-e": shell-expand-line
> "\e\C-g": abort
> "\e\C-h": backward-kill-word
> "\e\C-i": dynamic-complete-history
> "\e!": complete-command
> "\e/": complete-filename
> "\e@": complete-hostname
> "\e{": complete-into-braces
> "\e~": complete-username
> "\e$": complete-variable
> "\e\C-r": revert-line
> "\e\C-y": yank-nth-arg
> "\e\\": delete-horizontal-space
> "\e-": digit-argument
> "\ed": kill-word
> "\e\e": complete
> "\e>": end-of-history
> "\ef": forward-word
> "\eg": glob-complete-word
> "\e^": history-expand-line
> "\e#": insert-comment
> "\e*": insert-completions
> "\e_": insert-last-argument
> "\e.": insert-last-argument
> "\el": downcase-word
> "\en": non-incremental-forward-search-history
> "\ep": non-incremental-reverse-search-history
> "\e=": possible-completions
> "\e?": possible-completions
> "\er": revert-line
> "\e ": set-mark
> "\e&": tilde-expand
> "\et": transpose-words
> "\eu": upcase-word
> "\e_": yank-last-arg
> "\e.": yank-last-arg
> "\ey": yank-pop
> ```

---

Note: If you add a binding under `keymap emacs` to `vi-movement-mode` to try to switch straight to `vi-command` mode, the prompt doesn't update if you have `show-mode-in-prompt on`.

This is why the above solution adds `emacs` bindings to `vi-insert`. This makes for a longer `.inputrc`, but is required for a complete solution.