# Using vim keybindings in bash, is there a way to start in Normal mode?

Tags: bash, vi-mode

I just started using the vim key bindings in my bash terminal because I was constantly switching between the two and I just want to stick with one editing mode. Hence, I added the line `bash set -o vi` to my `.bash_profile` but one thing is bothering me is that you start in Insert mode rather than Normal mode. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash vi mode configuration to default to command mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24377/bash-vi-mode-configuration-to-default-to-command-mode)

Comment: well it does and does not at the same time, as in no one was able to give a solution that works and hence it could mean that this can't be done