# Exit out of Insert mode in Bash with Vi keybindings on command run

Tags: shell, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

I have bash set up with Vi keybindings, however when a command finishes running it returns to insert mode rather than movement mode.
I can use `bind '"\C-M":vi-movement-mode'` in my `.bashrc` to map the enter key to movement mode, but this does not allow the typed command to be run.
I can use

```bash
bind '"jj":vi-movement-mode'
bind '"\C-M":"jj\n"'
```

to exit out of movement mode when the enter key is pressed, but this returns to insert mode when the command is finished.

This is useful because it means I can enter a command, then use 'k' to scroll back through the command history, or use 'p' to paste another command, without having to exit insert mode every time.

How can I set up a single keybinding to run a command and exit out of insert mode?

Likely unnecessary info but I'm running on cygwin with windows terminal (painful but necessary).

Comment: Possibly relevant, if not a dupe: [Bash vi mode configuration to default to command mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24377)

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for the link, I have spent a while searching for a post on it.

Answer (score 0):

Update: As is usual with tech problems, I found the answer 20 mins after posting a question (and a long time searching for a solution). I found using `\njj` instead of `jj\n` did the trick. Not particularly nice but it seems to work.

Updated commands for anyone else with the same issue (put in `.bashrc`)

```bash
bind '"jj":vi-movement-mode'
bind '"\C-M":"\njj"'
```